# Update table with recent data from another table on most recent date, multiple entries

Tags: sql-server

Good evening everyone,

I feel pretty embarrassed asking this but I have been stuck at this for a few days now and am pretty desperate. I have found very similar problems that have been answered before but the problem is that I do not seem to be able to understand what is happening: [How to update another table with the most recent data in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981036/how-to-update-another-table-with-the-most-recent-data-in-sql)

So I have two tables Table1 and Table2 who are identical in column headers. Table2 is a table that is often renewed with updated locations, dates they were moved and by whom, sometimes the same item has been moved several times. I would like to update Table1 with the most recent information of Table 2.

```
Table1 
BarCode Location    MoveName    Movedate
245208  My Bench    an          24/11/2016
350474  room2       Tom         24/11/2016
350495  My Bench    mieke       04/08/2015
350500  room 4      Tom         17/10/2016

Table2
    F1  F2          F3       F4
350500  My Bench    Gert    24/11/2017  ---most recent
350495  room 8      Mieke   20/11/2016
350495  My Bench    Tom     30/11/2017  ---most recent
350500  room3       jan     17/10/2016
350495  living      Tom     4/08/2015

Solution
Table1
BarCode Location    MoveName    Movedate
245208  My Bench    an          24/11/2016
350474  room2       Tom         24/11/2016
350495  My Bench    Tom         30/11/2017  --updated
350500  My Bench    Gert        24/11/2017  --updated
```

I have been able to make a query that filters the data out of this table and I can make an update query to updat the table. I just don't seem to be able to do both at the same time...

Any help is most appreciated!
But foremost I would like to understand it too so I can help people in the future too. Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a `update - join` by getting the `MAX()` first and then perform a `join` like

```
update Table1 t1
join ( select F1, max(f4) as maxf4
       from Table2 
       group by F1 ) xxx on t1.BarCode = xxx.F1
set t1.Movedate = xxx.maxf4;
```

Per your comment that `xxx` is a table alias (OR) a inline view / inner table expression alias in this case for better redability and since am using a subquery to get the grouping result first.

Again, you said in comment *When I put this in an SQL query in access it gives me a syntax error...*

Are you using `MySQL` as RDBMS (that's per your post since you tagged that)? Or are you using `MS Access`? Cause if it's `MS ACCESS` then the suggested query won't work

Comment: Hi Rahul,  Thanks for the quick reply! Do you know of a good tutorial for this? I have been looking up the update-join but did not find good instructions so far. In the code you provide, what is xxx?  thx again!

Comment: Ok, after looking through it again with a fresh head I implemented your suggestion:   `UPDATE Table1
JOIN (SELECT F1, Max(F4) AS maxf4 FROM Table2 GROUP BY F1) xxx ON Table1.BarCode = xxx.F1
SET Table1.Movedate=xxx.maxf4;`             When I put this in an SQL query in access it gives me a **syntax error in update statement** and does not want to save. Any idea on what is wrong with the syntax? thx

Comment: @Tom, see edit in answer if that helps. and post your response.

Comment: Oh God... Yes I am using MS access and the sql that is embedded in it. I thought that was normal sql code you could use, no? Sorry for the tag but that was what was suggested and the ones I put in were not accepted.

Comment: I have been looking into it and indeed it is like you say, it is not possible to use this sql in access (just makes me wonder why they gave the option in the first place). Looks like I will have to solve this differently...Any ideas welcome. and thanks for your time, much appreciated!